# how to display a div on pageload in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to know how to display a particular div (not a page, just a div) on page load in jQuery Mobile. Here's the HTML:

```
    <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="sun">Sun</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="mon">Mon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="tue">Tue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="wed">Wed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="thu">Thu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="fri">Fri</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="sat">Sat</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
    <div id="sun" class="content_div">Sunday</div>
    <div id="mon" class="content_div">Monday</div>
    <div id="tue" class="content_div">Tuesday</div>
    <div id="wed" class="content_div">Wednesday</div>
    <div id="thu" class="content_div">Thursday</div>
    <div id="fri" class="content_div">Friday</div>
    <div id="sat" class="content_div">Saturday</div>

</div>
```

I'm using jQuery to negotiate the tabs, so my JS is above the jQuery Mobile source call. Here's that code:

```
    function getHandler(handler) {
        var days =  ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'],
            d = new Date(),
            today = d.getDay();

        for (x=0; x<days.length; x++) {
            if ( x === today ) { handler = days[x]; }
        }
    }

    $(document).delegate('[data-role="navbar"] a', 'click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
        $('.content_div').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
    });
```

My goal here is that when the doc initially loads, the div that corresponds to the current day of the week will be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getHandler() {
    var days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'],
        d = new Date(),
        today = d.getDay();
    return days[today];
}

$(document).delegate('[data-role="navbar"] a', 'click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
    $('.content_div').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-href="' + getHandler() + '"]').trigger('click');
})
​
```

Comment: thanks, never noticed your answer come through! For starters, the excessive for loop can be done away as it is simply looping until the value of `x` reaches that of `today` and then returns item at corresponding index of `days` array!!

Comment: Yeah. I was trying to modify his code as little as possible in case there were additional calls somewhere else.

Comment: @bPratik , any idea where I would add an ajax get request to dynamically create each of the content divs in my question above?

Answer (score 1):

I modified your getHandler() to return a value

The js code is as follows:

```
function getHandler() {
    var days =  ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'],
        handler = null,
        d = new Date(),
        today = d.getDay();

    for (x=0; x<days.length; x++) {
        if ( x === today ) { handler = days[x]; }
    }
    return handler;
}

$(document).delegate('[data-role="navbar"] a', 'click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
    $('.content_div').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
});

function displayTodayDiv() {
    var h = getHandler();
    $('.content_div').hide();
   $("#"+h).show();
}

$(document).ready(displayTodayDiv);​
```

Comment: `ready` is not a good event for binding when using jQuery Mobile. See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html